# create pivot table using sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, distinct, window-functions

I have a database called player.db

These database has two tables.

The tables called person and the other is called match.

person table is

| Player_ID | Player | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lionel Messi | Argentina |
| 2 | Luis Suarez | Uruguay |
| 3 | Neymar | Brazil |

match table is

| Match _ID | Game | Player_ID | Date | Season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Uruguay-Paraguay | 2 | 5/3/2019 | 1 |
| 2 | Uruguay-Chile | 2 | 19/3/2019 | 1 |
| 3 | Argentina-Chile | 1 | 22/3/2019 | 1 |
| 4 | Brazil-Guyana | 3 | 3/4/2019 | 1 |
| 5 | Brazil-USA | 3 | 1/6/2020 | 2 |
| 6 | Brazil-Belize | 3 | 3/7/2020 | 2 |
| 7 | Brazil-Suriname | 3 | 5/7/2020 | 2 |
| 8 | Argentina-USA | 1 | 8/8/2020 | 2 |
| 9 | Argentina-Canada | 1 | 3/3/2021 | 3 |
| 10 | Argentina-Grenada | 1 | 8/3/2021 | 3 |
| 11 | Uruguay-Suriname | 2 | 7/4/2021 | 3 |
| 12 | Uruguay-Mexico | 2 | 2/2/2022 | 4 |
| 13 | Uruguay-Jamaica | 2 | 4/2/2022 | 4 |
| 14 | Brazil-Ecuador | 3 | 5/2/2022 | 4 |

My pivot table should look like these:

| Season | Player |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Luis Suarez |
| 2 | Neymar |
| 3 | Lionel Messi |
| 4 | Luis Suarez |

I want a sql code which create a pivot table  which shows which player played most with topscore in which season year. For example Luis Suarez occured most in season 1.

I started coding  in sql, but got not the desired solution

```
SELECT Player_ID, COUNT(*)FROM match GROUP BY Player_ID HAVING COUNT(*) max
```

The problem is I got an error and it doesn't create a pivot table which show which player played most in which season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables, group by season and player to get the number of matches for each player and use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to pick the top player of each season:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Season,
       FIRST_VALUE(p.Player) OVER (PARTITION BY m.Season ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Player
FROM match m INNER JOIN person p
ON p.Player_ID = m.Player_ID
GROUP BY m.Season, m.Player_ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/F09o5RiH).

Answer (score 0):

Your clause `HAVING count(*) max` may cause the error.

The solution may depend on the relational data base you use. Here is a solution with postgresql :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Season)
       m.season, p.player, count(*) AS count
  FROM match AS m
INNER JOIN player AS p ON p.player_ID = m.Player_ID
 GROUP BY m.Season, p.Player_ID, p.player
 ORDER BY m.Season ASC, count DESC
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mf8Mgl6p)

Comment: Thanks, do you maybe know how to code in sqlite?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea about sqlite